# Styling multiselector box in Ext JS

Tags: extjs

[image]

How do you add text to the blue box to that encases the '+' symbol??? I have tried every variation of styling and attributs but I cannot find anything online or anything that works. Code is as follows so far:

```
items: [{
        xtype: 'multiselector',
        id: 'people',
        width: '25%',
        height: '80%',


        search: {
            xtype: 'multiselector-search',
            field: 'full',
            width: '15%',
            height: '80%',            
            store: {
                type: 'benefits_cards'
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, the names in my search box are full names.... but in the items spot they are just first name and I have no idea why. The field: 'full' refers to my data store value for 'fullname as full' and I have already tried putting fied full in the other part and no luck. Any help with these issues would be much appreciated! Below is a pic of what I am talking about with this other issue. 
[image]

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a text to the multiselector:

```
{
        xtype: 'multiselector',
        title: 'Test',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
 }
```

You can see the results here in the [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/30lr). Further documentation on the multiselector can be found [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.view.MultiSelector.html).

Please provide additional code in order to help resolve why you are getting only first name results when making a selection and would like to see full name in the results.